# Help, I Accidentally Corrupted my MediaTek Preloader

Tags: boot, rom, device-firmware, mediatek

Please help me, I have an Ulefone Note 7P and I wanted to upgrade my firmware, so I downloaded the latest of this [ROM](https://www.needrom.com/download/ulefone-note-7p/) and I got the SP Flash Tool and followed the guide on that forum.

So after loading Scatter and everything, I pressed start. The red line loaded (I marked Preloader) and after a while, I received an error (I have forgotten the error now) and now my phone won't boot. I think I loaded the preloader halfway and now my phone won't boot, or charge, or turn on, and my computer does not recognize my phone. It just says `unrecognized device`.

I have installed the Mediatek VCOM Drivers many times, it does not recognize my phone, the VCOM Drivers don't even work, they say "device cannot start."

Please help me, I really need this phone to work.

Edit: Thanks for the help, i followed the guides and opened up my phone but i did not use soldering iron, i just touched around inside with my fingers and i tried to connect and it worked, luckily i already started sp flash tool and put it in download mode to install the preloader so my phone is up and running now. And i've learnt my lesson and i'm never selecting preloader ever again.

Comment: https://forum.hovatek.com/thread-11802.html

Comment: you learned lession hard way: SP Flash Tool golden rule No 1 - always **uncheck** preloader, No 2 - don't trust any scatter file, No 3 - Never flash *"Format All + Download"* or *"Firmware Upgrade"* \*\*\* (\*\*\*except *"Download Only"* deny), No 4 - Do a readback first