# Can't access recovery partition Android 8.1 (Go edition)

Tags: recovery-mode, data-recovery, fastboot

Phone Maker: TECNO
Model: F1
OS: Android 8.1 (Go Edition)
Memory: 8GB ROM 1GB RAM

I have asked a question here:
[Android fastboot restoration points](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/228220/android-fastboot-restoration-points)

In summary the phone was updating then the battery died and now it is stuck in fastboot mode. It shows the text  `=> FASTBOOT mode...`  in the bottom left corner of the fully black screen.

I discovered its possibly a single slot device (does NOT support seamless system updates) and obviously the update process got bad. What are the ways to recover from this (fastboot mode screen) so the phone boots up correctly. I am currently using ADB, Fastboot to interact with the phone via USB. Below is the output that I get when I run 'fastboot getvar all' on a windows 10 system.

```
(bootloader)    max-download-size: 0x8000000
(bootloader)    partition-size:flashinfo: 1000000
(bootloader)    partition-type:flashinfo: raw data
(bootloader)    partition-size:userdata: 14ff80000
(bootloader)    partition-type:userdata: f2fs
(bootloader)    partition-size:cache: 7000000
(bootloader)    partition-type:cache: ext4
(bootloader)    partition-size:system: 59000000
(bootloader)    partition-type:system: ext4
(bootloader)    partition-size:keystore: 800000
(bootloader)    partition-type:keystore: raw data
(bootloader)    partition-size:secro: 600000
(bootloader)    partition-type:secro: raw data
(bootloader)    partition-size:oemkeystore: 200000
(bootloader)    partition-type:oemkeystore: raw data
(bootloader)    partition-size:metadata: 2500000
(bootloader)    partition-type:metadata: raw data
(bootloader)    partition-size:nvdata: 2000000
(bootloader)    partition-type:nvdata: ext4
(bootloader)    partition-size:tee2: 500000
(bootloader)    partition-type:tee2: raw data
(bootloader)    partition-size:tee1: 500000
(bootloader)    partition-type:tee1: raw data
(bootloader)    partition-size:frp: 100000
(bootloader)    partition-type:frp: raw data
(bootloader)    partition-size:vendor: 12000000
(bootloader)    partition-type:vendor: ext4
(bootloader)    partition-size:expdb: a00000
(bootloader)    partition-type:expdb: raw data
(bootloader)    partition-size:odmdtbo: 1000000
(bootloader)    partition-type:odmdtbo: raw data
(bootloader)    partition-size:logo: 800000
(bootloader)    partition-type:logo: raw data
(bootloader)    partition-size:para: 80000
(bootloader)    partition-type:para: raw data
(bootloader)    partition-size:recovery: 1000000
(bootloader)    partition-type:recovery: raw data
(bootloader)    partition-size:boot: 1000000
(bootloader)    partition-type:boot: raw data
(bootloader)    partition-size:lk2: 60000
(bootloader)    partition-type:lk2: raw data
(bootloader)    partition-size:lk: 60000
(bootloader)    partition-type:lk: raw data
(bootloader)    partition-size:seccfg: 40000
(bootloader)    partition-type:seccfg: raw data
(bootloader)    partition-size:persist: 3000000
(bootloader)    partition-type:persist: ext4
(bootloader)    partition-size:protect2: a00000
(bootloader)    partition-type:protect2: ext4
(bootloader)    partition-size:protect1: a00000
(bootloader)    partition-type:protect1: ext4
(bootloader)    partition-size:nvram: 500000
(bootloader)    partition-type:nvram: raw data
(bootloader)    partition-size:proinfo: 300000
(bootloader)    partition-type:proinfo: raw data
(bootloader)    partition-size:preloader: 40000
(bootloader)    partition-type:preloader: raw data
(bootloader)    off-mode-charge: 1
(bootloader)    warranty: yes
(bootloader)    unlocked: no
(bootloader)    secure: yes
(bootloader)    kernel: lk
(bootloader)    product: K80_BSP
(bootloader)    version-preloader: 0.1.00
(bootloader)    version: 0.5
all: Done!!
Finished. Total time: 0.142s
```

I tried the command
 `fastboot reboot recovery` but it responds ok and still displays the fastboot mode text

How can I:
1.) Recover the data by booting into the recovery partition (right now I am unable to access the recovery partition)
2.) Recover the data and boot the device via other means apart from recovery partition

Flashing the phone is a last resort. But is it possible to Flash the phone and still retain the data I had on it before this incident occured?

PS: For obvious security reasons I only intend to stick with official tools (ADB, Fastboot) to solve this problem. I am NOT willing to install any unofficial software on my computer.

Comment: @alecxs I intentionally removed the actual values and replaced them with xxx. It shows actual values I am able to see it in the command line output. When I use key combos I am able to get into recovery mode. But I do not want to do a factory reset, at least NOT yet.

Comment: ```fastboot reboot recovery``` is a command I have seen in the xda forums while researching into this matter

Comment: @alecxs I have modified the question above. been doing some research and found its possible to flash the stock rom via fastboot.

Comment: fastboot is disabled *(bootloader) unlocked: no* therefore your only hope is SP Flash Tool. in your case most likely only system.img must be flashed, and cache partition should be cleared. in any case your personal data is on userdata + metadata partition and should be backed up with valid scatter file (just to keep it safe)

Comment: scatter does not fit scatter file. you must [create scatter file](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/203283) for your own. Do a *"read back"* of your phone. in SP Flash Tool select [DA_SWSEC.bin](https://mega.nz/file/F2oiwA4A#vQfVAjeaimQX-wHw6N69CQLElEk_3gRmVEPJslTQ5io) as Download-Agent ([source](https://blog.hovatek.com/so-whats-all-this-talk-about-meditek-secure-boot-and-da-files)). you can follow below instructions afterwards

Comment: please note there is no official site for SP Flash Tool, but the tool itself is. however, the software provided by it's origin sources [spflashtools.com](https://spflashtools.com) and [4pda.ru](https://translate.google.com/translate?sl=ru&tl=en&u=https://4pda.ru/forum/index.php?showtopic=813767) (registration required) can be trusted

Comment: The plan is to unlock the bootloader to allow me flash the stock rom. Hopefully the phone will allow me to unlock the bootloader using the ``` fastboot oem unlock``` (not tried yet). Then I can download the ROM for the phone then flash it. Do I need to wipe my phone first before flashing? I intend to keep my data.

Comment: i have checked the scatter file provided by theggputest55 as you can see the discrepancy is for userdata partition (type ext4 vs f2fs) size 1.5 vs 5.25 GiB https://pastebin.com/upMT5X1v so you can use that scatter for flashing *system* but you can't use it for backup *userdata*

Comment: thanks for all the useful input. So in the current state the phone is in how do I backup the contents (all partitions)? Then I can flash using you suggested method then restore when the flashing is successful.

Comment: update the scatter file with proper partition size (0x14ff80000) for userdata (or [create](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/228396/cant-access-recovery-partition-android-8-1-go-edition?noredirect=1#comment298525_228396) new one), backup partitions from "read back"

Comment: https://android.stackexchange.com/q/220584

Comment: @alecxs , Thanks a lot for all of the feedback. I have obtained SPFlashTool using the link provided. Questions: 1)How do I create a scatter file for my device?(is it possible with SPFlashTool or can it be done via command line?)Now I know scatter file is basically a .txt file how do I get it from my device with SPFlashTool? 2)When I have the scatter file how do I use it to make a backup of my partitions? 3)Now when I want to flash the ROM, it is this same scatter file that I will use in SPFlashTool yes?

Comment: 1) download some similar scatter file and change the values with wordpad 2) you can't straight use the scatter file for [readback](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/220584) but you can create *readback entries* with that values 3) yes, except the ROM requires repartitioning (not recommended)

Comment: it is important first to install [VCOM preloader driver](http://www.google.com/search?q=MT65xx+Preloader+USB+drivers). the phones preloader is detected only for first ~1-2 sec when connecting, and only when phone is powered off. Therefore you must click start readback as 1st step and connect usb cable as 2nd step, readback will start immediately as soon as preloader is detected. [Tutorial step 5](https://forum.hovatek.com/thread-526.html) (skip step 1-4)

Answer (score 2):

You may be able to restore your phone using SP Flash Tool since you phone uses MediaTek CPU

1- [Download  SP Flash Tool](https://spflashtool.com/)

2- [Download the ROM from here](https://www.mediafire.com/file/hxu644bdoqkt3b7/F1-VP510EFG-GO-ETEC-181220V6.zip/file)

3- [Download the driver from here installation steps inside the zip "README" file](https://www.filesend.jp/l/en-US/K86Ipp)

4- power off you phone

5- open SP Flash Tool. Go to Download tab Click Scatter and Load Scatter File from ROM Folder

[image: imageedit-0-6226621777.png]

6-Select Download Only. Click Download & Connect the Switched off Phone

[image: imageedit-0-5557492297.png]

Comment: Thx for that answer. You could improve that with a warning one should always **un**check preloader https://android.stackexchange.com/q/227124

Comment: Thanks for the response. I hear fastboot can flash ROM also. Stumbled on instructions here https://forum.xda-developers.com/android/help/adb-fastboot-commands-bootloader-kernel-t3597181
I am comfortable with the command line so running commands isn't scary to me. Any input on how to achieve this with fastboot via CLI?

Comment: be aware *fastboot flashing unlock* will perform a factory reset which causes data loss

Comment: Thanks a lot for all of the feedback. I have obtained SPFlashTool using the link from @theggputest55.

Questions:

1)How do I create a scatter file for my device?(is it possible with SPFlashTool or can it be done via command line?)Now I know scatter file is basically a .txt file how do I get it from my device with SPFlashTool?
2)When I have the scatter file how do I use it to make a backup of my partitions? 3)Now when I want to flash the ROM, it is this same scatter file that I will use in SPFlashTool yes?

Comment: @thinkhjj Very sorry for the late reply modern android phones has about 50 to 100 partitions the Scatter File is like a map which tells the program where to read from the phone eMMC. in order to use SP Flash Tool you need two things 
1- a Scatter File which you can create by yourself by following is guide. 
https://tinyurl.com/helpyou148
or watch this vide to make yourself comfortable with tool
https://tinyurl.com/help458
2- DA agent aka download agent is a file that allows SP Flash Tool to read and write to the phone eMMC 
usually these two files exist with the backups created by users,